# Why won't this If statement work for the string?

Tags: java, string, math, if-statement, pow

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class Methods {

```
/*
 * Compound interest Program Quarterly
 */


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner  (System.in);

        System.out.println("What is the Rate");
        int rate = keyboard.nextInt()/100;
        System.out.println("What is the Amount");
        int amount = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("How many years?");
        int years = keyboard.nextInt();

        keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("How is it compounded? Press Q = Quarterly, A = Anually, S = SemiAnnualy, M = Monthly");

        String answer = keyboard.nextLine();

       int easy = amount*(1+(rate/years));
       int pow = 4 * years;


        if (answer == "/Q"){
            System.out.println("Your answer compounded Quarterly is: "  + Math.pow(easy,pow));
```

This is the code, but the if statement with String == "Q" doesn't work because when I press Q nothing happens? what's the issue?

Comment: Did you see the `/`?

Comment: Yes I sadly did, but it still doesn't work despite the / I just added it after looking at a similar question

Comment: You clearly do not understand the difference between the `==` operator, which compares reference values (object addresses) and the `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase` functions.

Comment: Yea another user just told me, thanks.,

Answer (score 0):

Java right? use equalsIgnoreCase because you could be typing 'q' and that / they told you about too, keep it in mind

Comment: I'm typing in the uppercase Q to test it, I can't even test it because it ignores the upppercase Q it's not the lower case

Comment: try to debug using answer.lenght() and System.out.println("OOO"+answer+"OOO"), maybe java is adding the line feed to your answer and that's why it fails the check.

regardless, still use equalsIgnoreCase so peopel can type both Q and q

Answer (score 0):

First issue is that you have a typo (the forward slash) in this line:

```
if (answer == "/Q"){
```

The second issue is that you don't compare strings like this.
Instead use the "equals()" method.

```
if(answer.equals("Q")){
```

See here for more information: [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try

```
if(answer.equals("Q"))
```

Comment: Yeah this worked, but I still would like to understand why the prior one didn't work thanks for this though ill probably just switch to this

Comment: @WinterOne **==** just do check for if these two object are exactly same one, and **equals** do the check if two string has came content.